# How can I do WCF Non-HTTP Activation with .Net 4?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a .Net 3.51 service which uses Non-HTTP Activation. This works fine. I want to convert it to .Net 4.

In Windows 7, if you go to Control Panel, Add Remove Programs, Turn Windows Features on or off, there is a "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1, WCF Non HTTP Activation" item.

How would I do this for .Net 4 ?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact turning it on for 3.5.1 turns it on for 4 too. I got exceptions because the appdomain reverted to .net 2. The non http activation works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Posting what worked for me since there's a few conflicting or outdated instruction sets out there.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/namedpipe-activation

> From the Start menu, choose Control Panel.
>
> Select Programs and Features.
>
> Click Turn Windows Components on or Off.
>
> Expand the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 node and check the Windows
>   Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation feature.

I just did it for 4.5:

[image]