# WCF and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, wcf

So I have a server that I host a web app on. It is a ASP.NET web app. I am try to push a second app on this sever. This is a Silverlight app. This uses a WCF service to populate a data grid. The problem is when I install the .Net 3.0 feature of HTTP Activation it kills my ASP.NET app. Is there any way for them to play nicely?

Comment: Can you define "kills my ASP.NET app"?  Does it cause specific error messages to occur on the ASP.Net app?

Comment: @mellamokb I get an error message about it not knowing what to do with HTTP Activation. I had to uninstall WCF Activation to be able to even access my ASP.NET app.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419620/how-can-i-do-wcf-non-http-activation-with-net-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It turns out if you turn on WCF in features, you need to reinstall .NET 4 in order for you to be able to use .NET 4 web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that one is a .net 3 app and the other is a .net 4 app? If so, you might need to have them run under different app pools, with each pool set to the correct version of .net. If they share the same app pool, it is quite possible that one app could kill the other.

Comment: They are both .NET 4 apps but the problem is on Server 2008, it only has .Net 3.0 as a feature.

Comment: So you can not set the app pool to use .net 4? Does the server actually have .net 4 installed?

Comment: It is set to 4.0 but the option provide to me in the features section of Windows Server is only 3.0

Comment: Oh I see, according to this question, the .net 3 option turns it on for .net 4 too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419620/how-can-i-do-wcf-non-http-activation-with-net-4  Sorry for my confusion, I thought you were just talking about the .net version and wasn't taking WAS into account.

Comment: I saw that but my question is why does this affect my preexisting applications?